# How can I add URL's dynamically to Protractor tests?

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to use protractor in conjunction with Jenkins. In my jenkins, I need to have URLs dynamically generated.

So while running protractor tests, for example:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    // Load the AngularJS homepage.
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('testUser');

  });
});
```

In above example I want to pass a variable dynamically in place of "http://www.angularjs.org".

I could not find any variables that can be specified in the reference config as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the environmental variable to configure the base url.  In that case, since Protractor is built on WebDriver you should be able to set

```
webdriver.base.url="http://someurl"
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I think this is the one. I will work on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `baseUrl` as config parameter inside `exports.config` and then use `browser.get('/path')` inside your test spec. So in config you have e.g. `baseUrl: 'http://localhost',` so `browser.get('/path')` would call `http://localhost/path`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like calling `browser.baseUrl = "https://test-url.com"` does the trick in `onPrepare`

Answer (score 0):

you must have conf.js or conf.ts file. So, You can set "baseUrl" as part of your conf file under config

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  baseUrl: 'my-site.com'
}
```

then call this browser in your test like:

```
browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
```

I faced same issue and resolved like this.