# How to set protractor(v1.4.0) baseUrl using protractor API instead of configuration file?

Tags: dynamic, set, protractor, base-url

i use protractor v1.4.0 and I want to set protractor baseUrl from command line so i can't use

`baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',`

config option in protractor configuration file. I want to define default value for base url with "params" option in protractor configuration file as follows:

`params: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    },`

and then overwrite the default value by passing a new value from command line when i run protractor as follows:

`protractor 'path_to_my_conf_file' --params.baseUrl http://localhost:80/`

then in my spec file i need to set base url using protractor API, but i can't find how to do that.

The 1-st answer to the following question is exactly what i need but it doesn't work.

[How can I add URL's dynamically to Protractor tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062369/how-can-i-add-urls-dynamically-to-protractor-tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just change it from the command line like so:

```
protractor --baseUrl http://whateveryouwant
```

Answer (score 7):

As another option, could also try `browser.baseUrl = "https://test-url.com"` in `onPrepare` (works in Protractor 1.4.0)

Answer (score 2):

Run tests via `grunt` with [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-protractor-runner) and [`grunt-option`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) libraries:

```
protractor: {
    options: {
        configFile: "path_to_my_conf_file",
        args: {
            baseUrl: grunt.option('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:80/')
        }
    }
}
```

Then, run the task via:

```
grunt protractor --baseUrl=http://mynewurl
```

And, to let it use the default `baseUrl`, just run:

```
grunt protractor
```

Comment: I would like to do that without grunt and i believe that there should be a way to set baseUrl just with protractor API.

Comment: @SurenAznauryan and `protractor --baseUrl=http://mynewurl` is not working for you, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use gulp for your test run; shown below is the `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor;

gulp.task('protractor', function() {
  var configFile = 'test/e2e/protractor-config.js';

  return gulp
  .src(['./test/e2e/spec/sample.js'])
  .pipe(protractor({
    configFile: configFile,
    args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://www.google.com']
  }))
  .on('error', function(e) { throw e; });
});

gulp.task('test', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'protractor',
    callback
  );
});
```

Task run:

```
gulp test
```