# setting environment parameter for protractor e2e tests

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, angularjs-e2e

We are using protractor to test our front end angular app that we are building.

Currently we are using `browser.get()` to specify our environement we wish to test again(localhost:9000, staging, UAT) however I am wanting to parameterize this so that when we run our tests using `grunt test:e2e` we can specify a parameter to change the `browser.get()` to a specified environment.

Something like being able to call `grunt test:e2e NODE_ENV=uat` to test against specified environment.

Anyone have any insight to how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass any number of arguments to protractor
You need to pass parameters within the protractor task in your grunt file. Here is small snippet

```
config: grunt.file.readJSON('config-param.json'),
protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: "config/e2e.conf.js", // Default config file
            keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails. 
            noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
            debug: '<%= config.debugger %>',
            args: {
                params: '<%= config %>'
            }
        },
        run: {}
    },
```

and you can access parameters in your specs like. browser.params.fieldName

Comment: I see that i can put `baseUrl:` into the params field of the grunt file, however can i have a task runner that specifies the `baseUrl` to use? 

Even being able to call `browser.params.baseUrl` in my specs, this wont help with being able to run tests specific to my environment.

Answer (score 4):

The common way to approach the problem is to use [`baseUrl` command-line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951009/how-do-i-parameterize-the-baseurl-property-of-the-protractor-config-file):

```
protractor --baseUrl='http://localhost:9000' protractor.conf.js
```

Or, you can set the [`webdriver.base.url` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062369/how-can-i-add-urls-dynamically-to-protractor-tests):

```
webdriver.base.url=http://localhost:9000
```

You can also use a task manager (e.g. `grunt` and [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner)) and configure different tasks for running tests in a different environment setting different `baseUrl`s.

Comment: Thanks for that! 

I've figured out that I can set the grunt task manager to have something like: 

`else if (target === 'e2euat') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'env:uat',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'express:dev',
        'protractor'
      ]);
    }`

However the problem i'm not trying to solve is how to pass in this task to the browser.get() in my spec file for when navigating "home"

Comment: @user249656 whenever you are using `browser.get()`, use relative to base urls, e.g. `browser.get("index.html")`.

Comment: Thanks! 

So i think grunt-protractor-runner is the route i should be taking. Fortunately, i noticed that our `Gruntfile.js` is already referencing protractor where we specify the `protractor.config.js` file. If i specify the `baseUrl: "http://localhost:9000"` in `protractor.config.js` then we are always going to be navigate to localhost rather than a parameterized environment. 

Is there a way to get the task manager to update the different `baseUrl`'s? I dont see anything in the docs that i've read through:\ Maybe a way to say `baseUATUrl:`?

Comment: Hi, can anyone guide on how to set baseUrl using `gulp task`